# How to work with Gmail attachments on Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, gmail, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic app where I get emails from a Gmail Account and I want to post the attachment of the email to my rest API. But I don't understand which type I get as the attachment. I have seen: if I use the Outlook.com trigger I get a base64String but from Gmail I get something else.
Is there an example how to work with Gmail attachments.

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify the expected behavior? What format do you need to send to the endpoint?

Comment: Is one of my endpoints so I can decide it. But normally i use base64 strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the input SahadevSinh. I have changed my workflow like this:
[image]

And in my endpoint I do this:

```
 public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MissionOutputDto> CreateMissionFromMail(HttpRequestMessage req)
    {
        string body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic fileData = JObject.Parse(body);
        string email = fileData.email;
        JArray files = fileData.files;

        string fileString = null;
        string fileName = null;
        string mimeType = null;

        foreach (dynamic file in files)
        {
            fileString = file.ContentBytes;
            fileName = file.Name;
            mimeType = file.ContentType;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

i have to one example to show you how you can get gmail attachment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLDnQ.png)

1) receive email trigger :

[Step 1 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVUFq.png)

2) get email details :

[Step 2 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaIKU.png)

3) pass attachment details in HTTP request
    [Step 3 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkpiW.png)

```
   [
  {
    "Name": "test (2).txt",
    "ContentBytes": "dGVzdA==",
    "ContentType": "text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"; name=\"test (2).txt\"",
    "ContentId": "",
    "Size": 4
  },
  {
    "Name": "test (2) - Copy.txt",
    "ContentBytes": "dGVzdA==",
    "ContentType": "text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"; name=\"test (2) - Copy.txt\"",
    "ContentId": "",
    "Size": 4
  }
]
```

"contentbyte" : is base64Strig

**WebAPI changes :**

you have create one more class to retrieve this attachment data

```
public class GmailAttechment
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentBytes { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }

        public string ContentId { get; set; }

        public int Size { get; set; }

    }
```

this class use to retrieve attachment details from your request

2. add above class into your webapi request parameter

   public class GetEmailDetails
       {
           public string file { get; set; }

   ```
       public string fileName { get; set; }

       public string from  { get; set; }

       public string mimeType { get; set; }
       **public List<GmailAttechment> GmailAttechmentList { get; set; }**
   }
   ```

   3. example of action

   public void GetGmailDetails(GetEmailDetails gmailDetails)
           {
               foreach (var item in gmailDetails.GmailAttechmentList)
               {
                   //here you can get all file content
                   string base6String = item.ContentBytes;
               }
           }

Comment: i am not sure but i can't use a dynamic content with the name attachment in the http request

Comment: please review edit answer and still you have doubt just lets me know because i invest my valuable time to solve this issue

Comment: i have been new code example for you understand how you can parse json in to list

Comment: please review it and lets me know if there is any problem